# JavaScript method isn't found

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an 'object':

```
function Rock()
{
    this.size = 30.0;
    this.body;
    this.isDead = false;

    this.vertexPosBuffer;
    this.vertexColBuffer;
}
```

which I give a function:

```
Rock.prototype.Tick = function()
{
    this.body.ApplyForce(new b2Vec2(0, 10), this.body.GetPosition());
}
```

and then I make an array of rocks:

```
var rocks;
function NewRandomRock()
{
    var newRock = new Rock;
    var pos = new b2Vec2;
        pos.x = Math.random()*(gl.viewportWidth+1);
        pos.y = Math.random()*(gl.viewportHeight+1);
    newRock.InitRand(pos);
    rocks.push(newRock);
}
```

and then I call the Tick function:

```
function TickRocks()
{
    for(var rock in rocks)
    {
        rock.Tick();
    }
}
```

Now the problem, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'Tick'

Though the "InitRand(...)" methods, which I add to the Rock the same way, does work...

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that using `for in` is not made for iterating over arrays. It's made to enumerate over object properties.

You should use a normal for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rocks.length; i++) {
    rocks[i].Tick();
}
```

Comment: That's just stupid! But ah well, now I learned something :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your variables:

```
function Rock() {
    this.size = 30.0;
    this.body = {};     //Initialize at an object
    ...
}
var rocks = [];   //Initalize an array
function NewRandomRock() {
    ...
```

Also, since `rocks` is an array, I recommend to loop using `for( ; ; )`:

```
function TickRocks()
{
    for(var i=0, l=rocks.length; i<l; i++)
    {
        var rock = rocks[i];
        rock.Tick();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an 'Init' method which I use the initialize all the variables ;) (I do this because sometimes I need to re-initialize the object).

Thanks anyways :D